# Struts2 Tags: Fielderrors tag

Tags: java, forms, jsp, struts2, tags

I am currently using Struts2 tags for my form, and to show its error messages. My question is that the default markup for showing error messages in Struts2 tags is the usage of `<ul>` tag. is there anyway I can change this? I want the error messages to be displayed as `<span>` not a list.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to change the CSS for UL elements.

This approach works only if you specifically care about appearance, not the DOM itself.

Comment: Great suggestion!!  forgot about that. I only care about  its appearance.

Answer (score 3):

The tags render according to their theme. The question then changes to: How do you change the theme? You can change it for the tag 
(set theme attribute on the tag to simple), page, request, or generally.

http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/struts-2-themes.html

Personally I like writing html, that is I don't like any "help" from the struts2 default theme. So in my struts.xml I simply use:

```
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
```

Web developers should know html.

**Update**:

Generally use YUI reset.css so I probably missed this...

If you extend ActionSupport on the action there is a `getFieldErrors()` method so you could use `<s:property value='fieldError["field_name"]'/>` that will return the associated error message string of course without any formatting.

It isn't much less readable than the `<s:fielderror/>` tag... after all we need to use property tags all the time anyways.

Comment: I made my theme to simple, but the thing is when I use the fielderrors tag it generates a ul li for the list of errors, which I do not want.

Answer (score 3):

You can override template files which are used for rendering errors. Copy `actionerror.ftl` and `fielderror.ftl` files from the `simple` theme from `struts2-core` jar to your application  and modify them not to use `ul`/`li` tags.

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue I used following code to resolve my issue

```
<s:if test="fieldErrors.get('email').size() > 0">
     <s:property value="fieldErrors.get('email').get(0)"/>
</s:if>
```

Where email is name of my field. This way we don't have to modify CSS.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a tutorial to show the use of the Struts 2′s ActionError and ActionMessage class.

http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-actionerror-actionmessage-example/

1. **ActionError** – is used to send error feedback message to user – display via < s:actionerror/ >

   ```
   <s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
     <div class="errors">
      <s:actionerror/>
      </div>
   </s:if>
   ```
2. **ActionMessage** – is used to send information feedback message to user,display via  < s:actionmessage/ >

   ```
   <s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
     <div class="welcome">
       <s:actionmessage/>
     </div>
   </s:if>
   ```

Comment: but does these to generate li and ul as its markup? I don't want to generate error messages as ul

Comment: Have you looked at the example in that link? I am not getting what are you saying. Could u add some sample code here in you question for support.

Comment: You should really read the question before posting. Don't post answers for mileage and confuse others. the question is about fieldError tag, not actionError or actionMessage.. isn't that easy to differentiate?